# Custom Formula Error

Tags: formula

I have a requirement where I need to calculate the date difference(no of days) between the leads accepted or rejected by sales on a custom field. The date calculated should only consider the working days which excludes the weekends.
I try creating this formula but it throws some parameter error also not sure if this will work as expected. 
Please help me to correct this formula also suggest if there are any better ways to achieve this

```
IF(
 AND(ISBLANK(Sales_accepted_date__c),ISBLANK(Sales_Rejected_Date__c)) ,

 CASE(IF( NOT( ISBLANK(SALES_accepted_date__c)) ,
CASE(MOD( createddate - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 
  0 , CASE( MOD( SALES_accepted_date__c - createddate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
  1 , CASE( MOD( SALES_accepted_date__c - createddate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
  2 , CASE( MOD( SALES_accepted_date__c - createddate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  3 , CASE( MOD( SALES_accepted_date__c - createddate ,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  4 , CASE( MOD( SALES_accepted_date__c - createddate ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  5 , CASE( MOD( SALES_accepted_date__c - createddate ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
  6 , CASE( MOD( SALES_accepted_date__c - createddate ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
  999) 
  + 
  (FLOOR(( TODAY() - createddate )/7)*5),

IF( NOT( ISBLANK(SALES_Rejected_Date__c)) ,
CASE(MOD( createddate - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 
  0 , CASE( MOD( SALES_Rejected_Date__c - createddate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
  1 , CASE( MOD( SALES_Rejected_Date__c - createddate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
  2 , CASE( MOD( SALES_Rejected_Date__c - createddate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  3 , CASE( MOD( SALES_Rejected_Date__c - createddate ,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  4 , CASE( MOD( SALES_Rejected_Date__c - createddate ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
  5 , CASE( MOD( SALES_Rejected_Date__c - createddate ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
  6 , CASE( MOD( SALES_Rejected_Date__c - createddate ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
  999) 
  + 
  (FLOOR(( SALES_Rejected_Date__c - createddate )/7)*5))
)))
```

Answer (score 1):

please check out this link for this, it is similar to your question

https://success.salesforce.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&id=90630000000gv44AAA